# Google's photo sphere functionality for Samsung TouchWiz phone?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, photos, samsung-touchwiz

My vanilla Android tablet (4.2/4.3) has this very fun feature in the camera app, that allows easily creating StreetView-like 360° composite pictures.

My Samsung TouchWiz phone (4.2) does not have this same feature in camera app. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just download the Nexus' camera app onto your Samsung device and install it. You'll end up with 2 camera and gallery apps. They all have different icons, though, so you can visually see which one you want to open.

See the following link for a download link and instructions.

Use the Google camera app to create photospheres. Note that to view the photospheres, you must also use the Google Gallery app (which is also installed).

http://www.intellectdigest.in/how-to-install-photosphere-on-samsung-galaxy-s4-without-rooting-on-touchwiz-ui-3529/?ModPagespeed=noscript

Direct download: http://d-h.st/tK6

---

Camera Icons

[image: Camera Distinction]

---

Gallery Icons

[image: Gallery Distinction]

---

In [ADW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher), I created a folder called Camera and changed the icon names for the two camera apps to help distinguish between the two. I don't know if TouchWiz can created folders or change the icon labels, though; I installed ADW Ex as soon as I got the phone.

[image: Labels on Desktop]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! (GT-I9295) TouchWiz does not allow renaming, but it does however allow folders with custom names (even in the app drawer) so I can place the Google's camera into a folder named Google.

Comment: I tried this on my Samsung Galaxy A6 but it doesn't allow me to install it anyway. The direct link is dead, but I found it here: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/camera/camera-5-2-025-198487658-release/google-camera-5-2-025-198487658-android-apk-download/

Answer (score 0):

### How to create 360° photos with your smartphone

Google has integrated the 360 ​​feature into the "Street View" app, the successor to the Camera app.

That does not mean you have to upload them to StreetView.  You can save the equirectangular JPGs in full resolution on the device and use with the (web) app of your choice!